# Django - list_filter not working with methods

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display =  UserAdmin.list_display  + ('get_company',)
    list_filter = UserAdmin.list_filter + ('get_company',)
    inlines = [CompanyInline,]

    def get_company(self, obj):
        assignment = UserCompanyAssignment.objects.get(user__exact=obj.id)
        return assignment.company.name
    get_company.short_description = 'Company'
```

The list_filter doesn't work with for 'get_company'. It says

```
'MyUserAdmin.list_filter[3]' refers to field 'Company' that is missing from model 'User'.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list_filter` must point to model fields, not methods. You can point it to [foreign keys](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), but for that to work in your case you must have changed the User model which I assume you haven't since you didn't post it.

I'm guessing the exception mesage refers to field 'Company' because you set `short_description` to 'Company'. Somewhat misleading, maybe a change in Django would be appropriate.

To do custom filtering, you can write your own `FilterSpec`, but it is not an official API yet.

---

`list_display` may contain methods, and if you want to do sorting on them, you can tell the admin to use a specific field by setting the `admin_order_field` attribute, like this:

```
def get_company(self, obj):
    # ...
get_company.admin_order_field = 'somefield'
```

Comment: Is there any FilterSpec available?

Comment: Yes, see http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/filterspecs.py for the code, and these two snippets: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/ http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1963/
I haven't used these myself so I cannot vouch for them.